# Dividers of a number n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $n=p_1^{2a_1}p_2^{2a_2}...p_n^{2a_n}$

Number of divisors of $n$:

$(2a_1+1)(2a_2+1)...(2a_n+1)$

I saw an other similar question, but it is complicated. There should be an more easy answer.

Comment: What is your question? (Also: asking three questions here in the last hour suggests that you don't spend much time on one before you give up and post for us.)

Comment: I love the simplicity of this proof that it's a necessary condition.

Comment: Whoa!  To be honest I've never seen the proof: $n = \prod p_i^{b_i}$ and the number of factors is $\prod (b_i + 1)$.  This number is odd if and only if every single $b_i$ is even.  I actually really *like* that proof!  I might even like it better than the one I *have* seen many times that factors come in $a, \frac Na$ pairs and the number of factors are odd if and only if there is a factor $a$ where $a = \frac Na$ if and only if $N = a^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's much more simple than that. For each divisor $d$ of $n$, $\frac nd$ is another divisor of $n$. So the divisors of $n$ come in pairs *except if there is a divisor $d$ such that $d=\frac nd$*. But this happens if and only if $n$ is a perfect square ($d=\frac nd\iff n=d^2$).

Comment: When this question is closed you should definitely move this answer to the duplicate.

Comment: @RobertFrost That's a nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note is "complimentary" factors come in pairs.

If the number is $N$ and $a$ is a factor of $N$, then $\frac {N}a$ is also a factor of $N$.

And for any factor $a$ you can match it up with the factor $\frac {N}a$.

List all the factors in order $1<a_1< a_2<.......<  a_m< N$.  Each factor $a_i$ gets matched up with $a_{m-i} = \frac N{a_i}$.

If $a_i \ne a_{m-i}= \frac {N}{a_i}$ for all $i$ then there are an even number of factors.

If the very middle factor is $a_i =  a_{m-i} = \frac N{a_i}$ then there is an odd number of factors.

If $a_i = a_{m-i} =\frac N{a_i}$ then $a_i^2 = N$ and $N$ is a perfect square.

And if $N$ is not a perfect square then that doesn't happen.